# Replace - with ' ' with gawk

Tags: regex, awk, gawk

I have this data set

Format
ID date delimited-characters

---

Here is a sample file

```
FILE data.txt
004 06/23/1962 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
023 11/22/1963 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
070 06/23/1963 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
```

My gawk script works fine like this

```
call gawk 'BEGIN { BLANK = " " } { print $2 BLANK $3 }' lottery.midday.txt

and I receive just data and data which is what I want
06/23/1962 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
11/22/1963 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
06/23/1963 AAA-BBB-CCC-DDD
```

But my problem is I dont know how to substitute `-` with 
I want to substitute dashes with blank spaces

```
gawk 'BEGIN { BLANK = " " } { print $3 BLANK $2 } data.txt
gawk 'BEGIN { BLANK = " " } { b=$3 gsub(/-/, " ") print} {print nb BLANK $2 }' data.txt
gawk { BLANK = " " } {print nb BLANK $2; gsub(/-/, " "); print }
gawk 'BEGIN { BLANK = " " RESULT=$3} {print gsub(/-/, " ", RESULT)} { print $3 BLANK $2 }' data.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
awk '{gsub(/-/," ",$3);print $2,$3}' file
```

with your input example, the line above outputs:

```
06/23/1962 AAA BBB CCC DDD
11/22/1963 AAA BBB CCC DDD
06/23/1963 AAA BBB CCC DDD
```

P.S. I just found that we have same username! ^_^

Comment: I wonder if I could make a living at cut/paste instead of coding   : )

Comment: "P.S. I just found that we have same username! ^_^" And this point causes some confusions. If I post a comment @Kent, you both receive the advice? P.S. You both also have "almost" the same rep... **`;-)`**